# Default password in .my.cnf for a specific user

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysqldump

We've got a backup script which takes a mysql dump every night, and to authenticate we've got a `.my.cnf` file with

```
[mysqldump]
password=somepass
```

However, every mysql user that doesn't pass in a password seems to inherit this password.

Is it possible to lock this into a combination? e.g.

```
[mysqldump@backupuser]
password=somepass
```

so it only gets used by that specific user?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use the following:

```
[mysqldump]
user=backup
password=password
```

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: From our testing, that just sets the default user AND password to those, it didn't do any logical checks e.g. "if user = backup, then password = password" it purely provides both to any mysqldump command

Comment: Every user is using his own account and thus has (or has not) his own  ~/.my.cnf

Comment: SSH user yes, but not mysql user :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using [MySQL socket connection and authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) with the socket user.

First you need to make sure you have `auth_socket` plugin installed.

Then the user needs to be created with:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

After this, when you log in as this user and connect to MySQL using UNIX socket, there is no password prompt.